# Realm Swift Embedded Objects. Views not updating when embedded objects data changes

Tags: swiftui, realm, realm-embedded-object

I'm trying to get my embedded objects to automatically update my SwiftUI code whenever they change. My code works under the following conditions:

1. When changes are made to the Parent Object itself.
   2.When I append a new Embedded Object to the Parent Object.

However my UI does not automatically update when I update a property in the Embedded Object.

'''

```
    class ParentObject: Object {
         @objc dynamic public var primaryKey = ""
         public let children = List<ChildObject>()
         public override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
         "primaryKey"
    }
    }

    class ChildObject: EmbeddedObject {
    let name = "Name"
    }

    class ParentObserver: ObservableObject {
    var parentResults: Results<ParentObject>

    var parents: [parent] {
    parentResults.map(parent.init)
    }
    //The embedded objects are placed in arrays inside "parents"
    
    {
    func newParent() {
    objectWillChange.send()
    //My view automatically updates to reflect the new parent
    }

    func newChild() {
    objectWillChange.send()
    //My view automatically updates to reflect the new child
    ParentObject.children.amend('a new child')
    }

    func updateChildName() {
    objectWillChange.send()
    //My view DOES NOT automatically updates to reflect the name change of the embedded 
    //object. If I exit and reenter the view the changed name show. Why does it not update 
    //automatically like the other cases?

    ParentObject.children.first(where: { whatever id }).name = "New Name" 
    }


    }
    }
```

'''

Comment: Why aren't you using Realm [Observers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/react-to-changes/#react-to-changes---ios-sdk) like this `notificationToken = results.observe` as that's what they are for. Using those will notify you of changes to the objects as well as removals, edits or additions to the to the  children embedded list.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Jay. I thought marking ObservableObject meant i'll be notified of all changes (sorry I'm new to programming). I'll look into implementing your suggestion.

Comment: Doh! SwiftUI... I overlooked that, my apologies. You need to use `@ObservedResults` etc to be notified of changes to a group of objects e.g. Results. Some good info about that in the docs [SwiftUI](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/integrations/swiftui/). If you want to work with an individual object, use [ObservedRealmObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/ObservedRealmObject.html).